# Setting different 'click_action' for web and ionic apps

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I have a web application (Angular 6) and mobile application (Ionic 4) and both are connected to the same database. And I'm using FCM ( Firebase Cloud Message ) for Push Notifications. I have followed 2 links 
1. https://www.djamware.com/post/5c6ccd1f80aca754f7a9d1ec/push-notification-using-ionic-4-and-firebase-cloud-messaging
2. https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/firebase-cloud-messaging-important-rest-apis-be79260022b5

I have created FCM "Group" for each user. This means a user can log in to the application using multiple devices ( browser OR mobile ) and this user will have one "fcm_notification_key" which consist of FCM token from different devices.

So now when the application pushes any notification to this unique "fcm_notification_key" key, all the devices ( web and ionic app ) connected with this key will receive. This is working perfectly.

```
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification Title",
    "body":"Notification Body",
    "click_action" : "myweb.com/specific_url",
  }
```

```
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification Title",
    "body":"Notification Body",
    "click_action" : "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
  }
```

First one is working with web and when a user clicks the notification, URL speicifed at "click_action" is open in the browser. Which is correct.

The second one is working with Ionic app. When a user clicks on the notification, it opens the Ionic app since "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" is specified for "click_action". This is also correct.

But the problem is, now I'm sending notifications to the Group ( which will contain web app and ionic app ). How should I send the data so that it will work for both web and ionic?

Comment: which group you are sending the notifications

Answer (score 2):

You can have a method in your json and based on the type, handle the event from a function

```
"notification":{
   "title":"Notification Title",
   "body":"Notification Body",
   "click_action: ()" : "click_action()",
}
```

TS:

```
click_action() {
  if(app) {

  } else {   
}
```

Comment: im not handling anything from client side... im send the notification back end and when user click on the notification, they ( web and ionic ) are automatically  handle the event

Answer (score 2):

Well you want to handle different types of `click_action` and other parameters per devices belongs to particular group of devices belongs to user,

If that is so then answer to this question is : you can merge notification payload options like given below, by customising parameters per device belongs to particular group, [for reference official documentation of group messaging](http://If%20I%20understand%20your%20question%20correctly%20then%20you%20want%20to%20handle%20different%20types%20of%20click_action%20on%20different%20divices%20belongs%20to%20particular%20group,%20%20%20to%20answer%20this%20question:you%20can%20merge%20notification%20payload%20options%20like%20given%20below,%20with%20customize%20parameters%20per%20device%20belongs%20to%20particular%20group,%20%20%7B%20%20%20%22name%22:%20string,%20%20%20%22data%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20string:%20string,%20%20%20%20%20...%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22notification%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20object%20(Notification)%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22android%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20object%20(AndroidConfig)%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22webpush%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20object%20(WebpushConfig)%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22apns%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20object%20(ApnsConfig)%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22fcm_options%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20object%20(FcmOptions)%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20//%20Union%20field%20target%20can%20be%20only%20one%20of%20the%20following:%20%20%20%22token%22:%20string,%20%20%20%22topic%22:%20string,%20%20%20%22condition%22:%20string%20%20%20//%20End%20of%20list%20of%20possible%20types%20for%20union%20field%20target.%20%7D%20%20so%20to%20answer%20your%20question%20for%20how%20to%20send%20custom%20data%20specific%20per%20device,%20so%20that%20it%20will%20work%20for%20both%20web%20and%20ionic,%20%20It%20will%20be%20something%20like%20given%20below%20%20%7B%20%20%20%22name%22:%20string%20%7C%20key,%20%20%20%22notification%22:%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22:%22Notification%20Title%22,%20%20%20%20%20%22body%22:%22Notification%20Body%22,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22android%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22click_action%22%20:%20%22FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY%22,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22webpush%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22click_action%22%20:%20%22myweb.com/specific_url%22,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20....%20%20%20....%20%20%20....%20%7D%20%20For%20reference%20link%20(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification))

```
{
  "name": string,
  "data": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "notification": {
    object (Notification)
  },
  "android": {
    object (AndroidConfig)
  },
  "webpush": {
    object (WebpushConfig)
  },
  "apns": {
    object (ApnsConfig)
  },
  "fcm_options": {
    object (FcmOptions)
  },

  // Union field target can be only one of the following:
  "token": string,
  "topic": string,
  "condition": string
  // End of list of possible types for union field target.
}
```

so to answer `How should I send the data so that it will work for both web and ionic ?`,

It will be something like given below

```
{
  "name": string | key,
  "notification":{
    "title":"Notification Title",
    "body":"Notification Body",
  },
  "android": {
      "notification": {
          "click_action" : "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
      }
   },
  "webpush": {
      "notification": {
          "click_action" : "myweb.com/specific_url",
      }
   },
    
  ...,
  ...,
  ...,
}
```

[For reference documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification)

Hope it helps, cheers :)

Comment: Hi, For android and iphone it is working fine. But for webpush, browser does not open with the link. What is the solution for that?